# How to reset an array that comes from struct

Tags: c

I've created this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char* id; 
    char* name;
    int birthYear;
    int finishedCourses;
    double avarage;
    int coursesNow;
    int courses[MAX_COURSES_YEAR];
}Student;
```

and now I am trying to set an array of courses.

this is what I wrote:

```
s1.courses[] = {5,4,3,2};
```

and the error is:

> student.c:15:13: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
>   s1.courses[]={5,4,3,2};

Comment: Still not working. error: student.c:15:13: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
  s1.courses={5,4,3,2};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialization of an array via an initializer list is only permissible upon declaration. So you can do:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

But you cannot do:

```
int arr[5];
arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

You have to use a loop or memcpy:

```
int tmp[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
// method 1
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(*tmp); i++) {
    arr[i] = tmp[i];
}
// method 2
memcpy(arr, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
```

You can also take advantage of compound literals and dispense with tmp array:

```
memcpy(arr, (int []) {1,2,3,4,5}, sizeof((int []) {1,2,3,4,5}));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int courses[]={5,4,3,2};
memcpy (s1.courses, courses, sizeof(courses));
```

Other way is to do so:

```
typedef struct {
    char* id; 
    char* name;
    int birthYear;
    int finishedCourses;
    double avarage;
    int coursesNow;
    int courses[];
}Student;

int courses[]={5,4,3,2};
Student *s = malloc(sizeof(Student)+sizeof(courses));
memcpy (s->courses, courses, sizeof(courses));
```

In this second case the advantage is that you alloc at runtime the very dimension for courses, you do not use padding space or statically fixed space for the field.

There are also other ways to do it.

Comment: I do not understand... int? the field is s1.course.

Comment: and if I  want to do it without dynamic allocation?

Comment: so what do I do to avoid the proble,?